# How do I stop apple from thinking I have two devices?

Tags: ipad

I downloaded some apps on my friends iPad using my own apple ID. I signed off but everything I downloaded went to my own IPad too. Now messages are popping up saying that I shouldn't delete certain things because they are on my " other device." How do I fix it so where apple doesn't think I have two devices?
Also, I sure my act of deleting the apps I downloaded for her affected her own IPad.

Comment: Could you upload a picture of the error message or perhaps a better description of what exactly it says and how you make it appear?

Answer (score 1):

In iTunes sign in to your Apple ID.

Then go to the iTunes store (top right), then click your account (top left). Once your account details load, there will be a section in the middle about **iTunes in the Cloud**.

You want **Manage Devices** on the right (but still in the middle) - click on it.

From there you can review all devices and remove the ones you no longer care to have associated with your Apple ID.